# Stop receiving again and again messages in consumer of the queue when an exception occurs in Spring JMS

Tags: java, spring-jms

I send a message from the sender application as below.

```java
    @GetMapping("send/event")
    public void sendEvent() {
        try {
            String stringEvent = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(getEvent());
            jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(false);
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(SEND_QUEUE_NAME, stringEvent);
        } catch (JmsException | JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And in the receiver application, I receive the message as below.

```java
    @Override
    @JmsListener(destination = "${mq.receive_queue}")
    public void receive(Message message) {
        try {
            String jsonEvent = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
            Event event = objectMapper.readValue(jsonEvent, Event.class);
            System.out.println(event.toString());
            message.acknowledge();
            validateEventRequest(event);
        } catch (JMSException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The main problem is when the `validateEventRequest(event);` has called. Because in this method, I have several services and scenarios that might raise an exception. I don't want if an exception threw, the message rollback to the queue and receive again. I just want to consume the message completely when an exception occurs.
Because of that, I added these lines to the sender application.

```java
  jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(false);
```

But nothing changes. I appreciate if anyone has idea about this.

**Additional information**
I called these in receive method of the receiver application

```java
int deliveryMode = jmsTemplate.getDeliveryMode(); -->2
int sessionAcknowledgeMode = jmsTemplate.getSessionAcknowledgeMode(); -->1
int jmsDeliveryMode = message.getJMSDeliveryMode(); -->2
boolean jmsRedelivered = message.getJMSRedelivered(); -->true
```

Comment: The exception can be anything in `validateEventRequest(event)` For example, I save the Event to the DB, so if I receive the message again and again I face with unique constraint (FIELD) violated exception JPA or if some remote APIs are down and etc.

Comment: Try catching `Exception` instead of `JMSException | IOException`. Throwing the exception out of the listener method is probably triggering the redelivery.

Comment: `Throwing the exception out of the listener method is probably triggering the redelivery.` This is exactly what I want to disable, because I have another exception in the `validateEventRequest(event)` process. Is it possible to shut down the redelivery?

Comment: I caught `Exception` instead of JMSException | IOException, Now It just throws the exception one time and it's good but why this could not be done with JMSException?

Comment: I posted an answer that hopefully clarifies things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your `validateEventRequest(event)` is throwing something other than `JMSException` or `IOException` (or one of their subclasses) which means the `catch` in your `receive` will *not* actually catch it. I believe that when this exception is thrown out of your `receive` method that will trigger redelivery on the message. I recommend you catch the more generic `Exception` instead, e.g.:

```java
@Override
@JmsListener(destination = "${mq.receive_queue}")
public void receive(Message message) {
    try {
        String jsonEvent = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
        Event event = objectMapper.readValue(jsonEvent, Event.class);
        System.out.println(event.toString());
        message.acknowledge();
        validateEventRequest(event);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, it's worth noting that changing how the message is sent has no impact on how the message is received. If you want to change how the message is received then you need to change the receiver application.

Comment: Thanks, Justin. You mentioned important points. Yes exactly `validateEventRequest(event)` is throwing something other than JMSException or IOException. But do you have any idea how can we shut down the redelivery in a manual way?

Comment: What do you mean "shut down the redelivery in a manual way"?

Comment: I mean changing the AcknowledgeMode to `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` or `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`. Because it seems if we set to `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` it acknowledges before listener execution and provides no redelivery in case of exception thrown. If I could set to this mode, I think if any exception occurs the message not rollback to the queue.

Comment: According to the [JavaDoc for `@JmsListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html) it uses `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` *by default* which clearly isn't working for you.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit weird that it does not work for me even that it is the default mode. Thanks for your answer.